# Autocorrelated residuals is a problem for a within-subjects ANOVA?

Tags: anova, autocorrelation

When participants arrived at the lab, I showed them curriculum vitae with different profile pictures and different types of university information. After viewing each curriculum, I asked participants to rate the competence of the person from 1 to 7.

So I have a within-subjects design with a Likert scale dependent variable and two categorical predictors (3 levels each). I am considering running a **repeated measures ANOVA**, but I am still checking the assumptions. **Are autocorrelated residuals a problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are. RM ANOVA assumes sphericity, which means that the variances of the differences are equal across time. If there is autocorrelation, then they won't be. Assuming that the autocorrelation is positive, the variances will be smaller between time 1 and 3 then between time 1 and 2 or 2 and 3.

I suggest using a multilevel model, which does not assume this.

Comment: Note that a multilevel model that only has random intercepts also assumes sphericity.  RM ANOVA is a step worse as many practitioners don't do the needed sphericity correlation-adjustment.